# qtip hide tooltip on specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip3

I have a table with qtip tooltip plugin. I want hidden tip in action column in the table. Try hide target option

```
 hide: {
    target: $('h1:first')
}
```

But that's not what I need

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>telephone</th>
      <th>mobile</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-tooltip="My tooltip text">
        <td>John</td>
        <th>3242123</th>
        <th>856966633325</th>
        <th><a href="#">edit</a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr data-tooltip="My tooltip text2">
        <td>Sarah</td>
        <th>5436346</th>
        <th>3543435345</th>
        <th><a href="#">edit</a></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

js code :

```
$('[data-tooltip!=""]').qtip({
    content: {
        attr: 'data-tooltip' // Tell qTip2 to look inside this attr for its content
    },

    show: {
        delay: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        fixed: true,

    },
    position: {
        target: 'mouse', // Use the mouse position as the position origin
        adjust: {
            // Don't adjust continuously the mouse, just use initial position
            mouse: false
        }
    },


});
```

I don't know how to display it in just about every part except action column

live version : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bofalo/5f7nL0d1/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Move `data-tooltip` attribute to `td` instead of `tr`. And add it in only those `td` in which you need to display tooltip. Updated `html` will be like below.

Here is updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fg6pzy1/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>telephone</th>
      <th>mobile</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-tooltip="My tooltip text">John</td>
        <th data-tooltip="My tooltip text">3242123</th>
        <th data-tooltip="My tooltip text">856966633325</th>
        <th><a href="#">edit</a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-tooltip="My tooltip text2">Sarah</td>
        <th data-tooltip="My tooltip text2">5436346</th>
        <th data-tooltip="My tooltip text2">3543435345</th>
        <th><a href="#">edit</a></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```